# Mobile First 7.1 SOAP Adapter failed to read response

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have used IBM MobileFirst Studio V7.1 - Service Discovery wizard option and created a SOAP adapter from a application WSDL file. The Service Discovery procedure correctly creates the MobileFirst adapter in the MFP Studio.
The sample message payload is as follows.

```js
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fet="http://siebel.com/asi/Fetch Account Info">
      <soapenv:Body>
      <fet:ExecuteFetchAccountInfo_Input>
         <fet:Object_spcId>1-6U8KAR</fet:Object_spcId>
      </fet:ExecuteFetchAccountInfo_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, using the adapter testing option in the MobileFirst Studio, the following JSON payload are being passed in the dialog window

params:

```js
{"ExecuteFetchAccountInfo_Input":{"Object_spcId":"1-6U8KAR"}}
```

But I get the following error when I call the adapter

```js
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Failed to read the HTTP response to: \/eai_enu\/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute \njava.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Also when I tried to check the log files. I was able to capture the request and response.

Request:

```js
[2/16/16 11:27:10:997 IST] 000001ce com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker             I FWLSE0318I: request:
/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<tns:ExecuteFetchAccountInfo_Input xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://siebel.com/asi/Fetch Account Info" xmlns:xsdLocal1="http://www.siebel.com/xml/Account%20IO" >
<tns:Object_spcId>1-6U8KAR</tns:Object_spcId>
</tns:ExecuteFetchAccountInfo_Input>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```js
response:
OK
Date=Tue, 16 Feb 2016 05:34:35 GMT
Server=Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By=ASP.NET
_charset=UTF-8
cache-control=no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
pragma=no-cache
transfer-encoding=Chunked
content-type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8
 [project IBMBankProject]
[2/16/16 11:27:11:000 IST] 000001ce om.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl E FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project IBMBankProject]SoapAdapter1/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project IBMBankProject]
Failed to read the HTTP response to: /eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute 
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project IBMBankProject]java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input streamjava.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read the HTTP response to: /eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute 
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

By looking at the response it says the response if Ok but it is unable to read it. Please help if I need to set-up something extra to read the response.

Comment: Try testing your SOAP request in SOAPUI or other tools. If it fails there as well there problem may be with the backend rather than MobileFirst.

Comment: I tried in SOAP UI it is working fine. But when tried to test via SOAP adapter in Mobile First its is getting failed

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a defect here that needed to be fixed.  The APAR number is [PI67417](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI67417) and it can be downloaded from [Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=7.1.0.0&platform=All&function=all).

Once you've applied the iFix, you'll also need to add "Accept-Encoding: identity" to your adapter call.  That should resolve your issue.  If it doesn't please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is working in SOAP UI but fails in the adapter, it may indicate a product defect. Please open an IBM PMR and provide your files for reproduction by the development team.